# GROUP BY a small subset of returned fields

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose I want to select from a table ABC containing fields A,B,C,D,E where E is a numeric field.

For a given combination of `A` and `B` I want to return the row containing the maximum value of `E`. How do I do this? What do I `GROUP BY`?

If I try to GROUP by A,B while putting max only around E, I get the "`not a GROUP BY expression`" error, but I do want to GROUP only by A,B.

I tried

```
select A,B,C,D,max(E)
from ABC
group by A,B
```

and this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not require `group by`.  A typical way is:

```
select abc.*
from abc
where abc.e = (select max(abc2.e) from abc abc2 where abc.a = abc2.a and abc.b = abc2.a);
```

However, this will return duplicates if multiple rows have the same maximum `e` value.  Another method uses ANSI standard window functions:

```
select abc.*
from (select abc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by e desc) as seqnum
      from abc
     ) abc
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one (arbitrary) row, if there are duplicate maximum `e` values.  You can use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()` if you want the duplicates using this method.

Comment: Which of these two will perform better? Is there any way to get rid of the intermediate table containing the row_number() column and instead pick up the required rows for each combination of A and B using just the WHERE clause on ABC in the original query? In other words, can I integrate PARTITION and the picking up of the required row with the WHERE clause?

Comment: I preferably want something like this. select * 
from ABC where
rank() over (partition by (ABC.A 
 , ABC.B
 ) order by ABC.E) = 1
For this, I get the error "window functions are not allowed here".

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*
from ABC t1
join
(
    select A,B,max(E) as maxE
    from ABC
    group by A,B
) t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and t1.e = t2.maxE
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to avoid joins and nested queries? PARTITION is one way- for instance.